# How to get an element's html from a page that represent the content as it is exactly including all the styles applied over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, browser

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve the exact HTML of a form, including all the applied styles (CSS). My goal is to mimic the behavior of Google Forms, which sends a response via email.

I've attempted to use the `.innerHTML` and `.outerHTML` methods, but they don't include the external CSS applied to the element. Specifically, I want to extract the HTML of an element having className let's say `formSubWrapper` while preserving all the styles.

Comment: *"My goal is to mimic the behavior of Google Forms, which sends a response via email."* - How does this task contribute to the stated goal?  I doubt Google Forms does it this way.  Surely they've simply styled their emails to meet their needs.  It's not clear to me why you think you need to scrape this information from a web page, and I suspect this is very much an XY Problem.  Can you clarify why your email can't just contain whatever HTML/CSS you want it to?

Comment: Well you are correct. But what would you suggest for extracting the exact html css for that content to show the element as it is.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that at all.  I would suggest styling your emails the way you want to style them.  If you have the entirety of a page (including all styling and functionality) then you can "render" it in memory with browser engine tools, such as Selenium.  But to isolate only a part of that page and somehow intuitively replicate the styling as it would have been displayed on the entire page sounds like a very ambitious AI project.  You might consider hiring a team to research and develop that over the course of several years.  Or reconsider your approach.

Comment: I see no (simple) way of doing this given the styling can change depending on context such as viewport size, so taking a 'snapshot' of styles as applied in a particular browser on a particular device etc wont be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very reliable because another element outside of your specific container/element can have an impact on your form styles. However, you may want to check out the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) web API. It helps you get all styles applied to a given element. You can just iterate over elements and gather their styles.

Comment: Wont this give the styles for that element in that context (e.g. on that viewport size with media queries) potentially, depending on how the original set the styling

Comment: @AHaworth Well, he can also gather the media queries by using `document.styleSheets`; however, I think doing such a thing on the client side is wrong by design.

Comment: Yes they can, but not by using just the method in your question.